# postgresql: how to import data from two separate tables into a single table into the SAME row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I am using postgresql to create `countries` table from `single_sales_records`.
`single_sales_records` looks like this:

```
sales_id |region                           |country| <Many other columns!>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |Australia and Oceania            |Tuvalu | ...
2        |Central America and the Caribbean|Grenada| ...
3        |Europe                           |Russia | ...
.
.
```

Before this, I created a `regions` table, which basically looks like this:

```
region_id | region
-------------------------------
1         |asia
2         |australia and oceania
3         |central america and the caribbean
4         |north america
5         |sub-saharan africa
6         |middle east and north africa
7         |europe
```

The `countries` table (1 region can have many countries) that I want to create is supposed to look like this:

```
country_id | country | region_id
-----------------------------------------
1          |korea    |1
.
.
.
```

I have a query that helped me to populate my 'regions' table:

```
INSERT INTO regions (region)
SELECT DISTINCT region
FROM single_sales_records;
```

And I am having trouble with my current query that is supposed populate by 'countries' table:

```
INSERT INTO countries (country)
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM single_sales_records;
INSERT INTO countries (region_id)
SELECT DISTINCT region_id
FROM regions;
```

When I do this, my 'countries' table doesn't match a country that is inside a region - instead it lists all the country, and then add 7 additional lines for the regions. it looks like this:

```
country_id | country | region_id
-----------------------------------------
1          |korea    |null
.
.
76         |haiti    |null
77         |null     |1
.
.
83         |null     |7
```

Can someone please help me to match the country with the associated region?

I tried to look for other so articles, but they were talking about inserting data INTO two separate tables, or talking about joins (i don't think this would exactly require join... right?).

Thank you so much!
[This article was edited to include single_sales_records]

Comment: Side note: Drop the `region` column in `countries`. You already have that information in `regions` and can get it from there.

Comment: @stickybit thank you for your advice. Could you please explain to me how I would do it without having `region`? I currently did not get to work this problem out. Thank you!

Comment: I'm no sure what you want to know now? How to leave the columns out? Remove it from the `CREATE TABLE` statement. How to get the name later? Join the regions table on the region id or use a correlated subquery.

Comment: @stickybit I would like to know how to data insert from `regions` and `countries` table into a new table into the same row where a country would be associated with a region. From the responses from you and @Gordon Linoff, it seems like I need to use join, but Gordon Linoff's solution is not working. Therefore, I would appreciate it if I could get a working solution (whether I include `region` in my new table or not) :)

Comment: How does `single_sales_records` look like? [Edit] the question and include a sample of it.

Comment: @stickybit Just edited :)

Comment: Why are the names all lower case in one sample but lower and upper case in the other? If you really used the `INSERT` you showed that shouldn't be and Gordon's answer should do it.

Comment: oh.. it was because I did lower and trim for countries. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `JOIN` the tables together for the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO countries (region_id, country)
    SELECT DISTINCT r.region_id, country
    FROM single_sales_records ssr JOIN
         regions r
         ON ssr.region = r.region;
```

Comment: @NathanBell . . . Please set up a db<>fiddle so I can see the code you are using.